# How to create a rich Text Editor using the new iOS 5 for the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiwebview, rich-text-editor

If I want to create a RTE using the new iOS beta for developers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

The same way you would on iOS 4, apple didn't release any new Rich Text editing stuff for developers (annoyingly).

The only new rich text editing apple added to iOS was in the Mail app (which was announced in the keynote, so not under NDA).

Have a look at some of these.

- **EGOTextView** : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egotextview
- **BCTextView** : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bctextview
- **JTextView** : http://codaset.com/jer/jtextview
- http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rich+text&commit=Search